# Selecting the 1st and 10th Records Only

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Have a table with 3 columns: ID, Signature, and Datetime, and it's grouped by Signature Having Count(*) > 9.

```
select * from (
    select s.Signature 
    from #Sigs s
    group by s.Signature 
    having count(*) > 9
) b
join #Sigs o 
on o.Signature = b.Signature
order by o.Signature desc, o.DateTime
```

I now want to select the 1st and 10th records only, per Signature. What determines rank is the Datetime descending. Thus, I would expect every Signature to have 2 rows.

Thanks,

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a couple of common table expressions.
The first will select all records from the table as well as a count of records per signature, and the second one will select from the first where the record count > 9 and add row_number partitioned by signature - and then just select from that where the row_number is either 1 or 10:

```
With cte1 AS
(
    SELECT ID, Signature, Datetime, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Signature) As  NumberOfRows
    FROM #Sigs    
), cte2 AS
(
    SELECT ID, Signature, Datetime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Signature ORDER BY DateTime DESC) As Rn
    FROM cte1
    WHERE NumberOfRows > 9
)

SELECT ID, Signature, Datetime
FROM cte2
WHERE Rn IN (1, 10)
ORDER BY Signature desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know what your data looks like, this might need some adjustment.

The simplest way here, since you already know your sort order (`DateTime DESC`) and partitioning (`Signature`), is probably to assign row numbers and then select the rows you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
select o.Signature
      ,o.DateTime
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.Signature ORDER BY o.DateTime DESC) [Row]
    from (
        select s.Signature 
        from #Sigs s
        group by s.Signature 
        having count(*) > 9
    ) b
    join #Sigs o 
    on o.Signature = b.Signature
    order by o.Signature desc, o.DateTime
)
WHERE [Row] IN (1,10)
```